# Get closest title element

Tags: jquery

```
<h3>Title 1</h3>
<div class="anything">Something</div>
<div class="anything">Multiple inputfields here... <input type="text" class="trigger"></div>

<h3>Title 2</h3>
<div class="anything">Something</div>
<div class="anything">Multiple inputfields here... <input type="text" class="trigger"></div>
```

How can I get the title when focusing an input field?

I tried this one:

```
$('body').on('focus', '.trigger', function() {
    var title = $(this).closest('.anything').prev('h3').text();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('body').on('focus', '.trigger', function() {
    var title = $(this).closest('.anything').prevAll('h3').eq(0).text();
});
```

Comment: buyt it will Always `<h3>Title 1</h3>` show only,as u show only 1st h1

Answer (score 1):

It should be :

```
var title = $(this).closest('.anything').prev().prev().text();
```

**[See DEMO here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/Lyhx5bb4/)**

OR

```
var title = $(this).closest('.anything').prevAll('h3:first').text();
```

**[See DEMO here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/Lyhx5bb4/1)**

Comment: Remove the `.parent()`. `.closest('.anything')` is already the parent you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery closest('X') method looks for the closest X matching **parent**. h3 is a sibling of the parent you're looking for.

What you really should do is wrap that stuff inside an element like such:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<h3>Title 1</h3>
<div class="anything">Something</div>
<div class="anything">Multiple inputfields here... <input type="text" class="trigger"/>
</div>
```

and then do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.trigger').on('focus',function(){ 
       alert($(this).closest('.wrapper').find('h3').text());
    });
});
```

**OR** if you insist in keeping your structure:

Here is a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ta4hmssb/)

For HTML

```
<h3>Title 1</h3>
<div class="anything">Something</div>
<div class="anything">Multiple inputfields here... <input type="text" class="trigger"/></div>
```

use the following line...

```
$(this).parent().prevAll('h3').eq(0).text();
```

alternatively to this you can use the not so pretty (but working) jQuery:

```
$(this).parent().prev().prev().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/tuL4vctr/

No out of the box way to do it but this is one option

```
$('body').on('focus', '.trigger', function() {
    var title = $(this).closest('.anything').prev().prev('h3').text();
    // Rest of your code 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Note: `prev()` returns the FIRST previous sibling. If you filter using a selector then it filters that first sibling, either returning the first sibling, or nothing. It does not search all previous siblings for the first sibling that matches the selector.

The following are equivalent:

```
var h3_1 = $(this).prev("h3")
var h3_2 = $(this).prev().filter("h3")
```

In the above example the previous sibling is always another `<div>`, so `prev("h3")` will never return anything.

To search all previous siblings you need to use the `prevAll()` method, and then filter on the first match.

```
var title = $(this).closest(".anything").prevAll("h3:first").text();
```

Comment: what is the difference between your's and OP's code?

Comment: Oh. Yeah, well in that case I don't know why his code isn't working.